# How to replace pages in pdf with bookmarks?

Tags: command-line, pdf, pdftk, master-pdf-editor

I have a pdf-file `pdf1` **with bookmarks** and I have another pdf-file `pdf2`. I want to replace all (or part of) the pages of `pdf1` with the pages of `pdf2` so that the bookmarks stay where they were. In Acrobat it's a trivial procedure, but how to do it in Unix? As I understand (or am I mistaken?), pdftk wipes off the bookmarks. Would be nice to do it in cli...

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you tried `pdfsam`?

Comment: @N0rbert I would prefer a cli, but anyway thanks! I'll take a look.